# Chrome Extension - Background Script notified whenever another page updates

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a Chrome Extension that gets the DOM of a closed tab and updates the popup.html. So far so good, I can do that through the background script using XMLHttpRequest.

However, I would like my popup to be updated if the closed page is updated. I was thinking of running a timer in the background script to check every 10 sends or so, but I was wondering if XMLHttpRequest has a way of knowing when its page updates? Or even if the timer would work, I couldn't get it working

I've added the relevant files below. Any help is appreciated

popup.html

```
  <body>
  <h1>Agile Board Viewer</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <button id="mainButton">Click me</button>
    <p id="testingDisplay">test</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            method : 'POST',
            action : 'xhttp',
            url : '//My url//',
            data : 'q=something'
        }, function (responseText) {
            document.getElementById("testingDisplay").innerHTML = responseText;
        });
    });
});
```

background.js
I've deleted some lines that are pointless (I think) to avoid clutter, just error handlers and what not, also got rid of my attempt at a timer. Basically, what it does is takes a string from the DOM and sends it to the popup. I would like that popup to update whenever the string does.

```
var testingString = "Testing (";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
`var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function () {
        var testingValue = xhttp.responseText.substring(xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString), xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString) + 16);


        callback(testingValue);
        //callback(xhttp.responseText);
    };
}
});
```

Sorry if the formatting is a mess, I'm not too well versed on this

Comment: onMessage listener needs `return true` to keep the channel open while async XHR runs, see the documentation. OTOH, you can invoke XHR in your popup script directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the original code I had, had return true but it still wasn't working. I managed to get it working using a timer and which checks the page every 5 seconds and if the label is different than before, I get my notification. I'm still learning XHR so this probably isn't ideal but it works for now and I don't see any major issues. I'll post my solution as a response. Once again, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, I've solved my issue by using a timer that checks the closed tab every couple of seconds. If the label that lists the number of items in my Testing column is different, I get my notification. Still learning XHR so I'm hoping I can improve on this again but for now, I'm happy enough. Only works for 20 seconds in my example, as I don't want an infinite timer. Will put in an off switch later

```
var testingString = "Testing (";
var testBuffer = "";
var i = 0;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';
        var testingValue = xhttp.responseText.substring(xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString), xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString) + 16);

        function startTimer() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                if (i < 20) {

                    xhttp.open(method, request.url, true);

                    xhttp.onload = function () {
                        testBuffer = testingValue;
                        testingValue = xhttp.responseText.substring(xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString), xhttp.responseText.indexOf(testingString) + 16);

                        if (testBuffer != testingValue) {
                            notification = new Notification('New Item in Testing Column', {
                                    body : "You have a new item in Testing",
                                });
                            console.log(testingValue);
                        }
                    };

                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                            callback(testingValue);
                        }
                    };

                    xhttp.onerror = function () {
                        alert("error");
                        callback();
                    };
                    if (method == 'POST') {
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    }

                    xhttp.send(request.data);

                    console.log("count");
                    i++;
                    startTimer();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        startTimer();

        return true;
    }
});
```